# `IndexSet` is never really empty?

Tags: swift

I stumbled across the following behaviour that I didn't expect:

```
let myIndexSet = IndexSet()
let index = myIndexSet[myIndexSet.startIndex] //index = 0
```

Doing a similar trick with an `Array` crashes with an out-of-bounds error as I would expect.

Why does `IndexSet` allow this? Is this expected behaviour that I can rely on? (It's actually quite useful for my situation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug - it directly contradicts the behaviour documented in [`Collection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection).

The documentation for [`Collection.subscript(Index) -> Element`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/subscript(_:)-887tm) says the following about its parameter:

> The position of the element to access. position must be a valid index of the collection that is not equal to the `endIndex` property.

and yet the following prints 0:

```
let myIndexSet = IndexSet()
print(myIndexSet[myIndexSet.endIndex])
```

Note that the index set *is* empty, as indicated by its `count` as `isEmpty` properties, and also the fact that its `startIndex` is equal to its `endIndex`.

```
print(myIndexSet.count) // 0
print(myIndexSet.isEmpty) // true
print(myIndexSet.startIndex == myIndexSet.endIndex) // true
```

Looking at its source code in the [swift-corelibs-foundation implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/Foundation/IndexSet.swift#L263), we can see exactly why:

```
public subscript(index : Index) -> Element {
    return index.value
}
```

It does no checking of whether itself is empty or not. The return value of this subscript depends solely on `index`! Looking at the blame, this line of code was added 6 years ago and no one changed it or reported this bug since then. I guess "this shouldn't work but it does" is just less easy to find than "this should work but doesn't" :)

I have since posted [this bug report](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/issues/4607).